# How docker process communication between different containers on default bridge on the same host?

Tags: docker, containers

Here is my situation：
First，I run a MySQL container(IP:172.17.0.2) on centOS;
Then I run a Nacos contanier with specified datasource(MySQL above) on the same host, but i didn't use the ip of the MySQL container, instead I used the ip of the bridge Gateway(172.17.0.1)(two containers both link to the default bridge).

What surprised me was that Nacos works well, it can query config data from MySQL container normally.
How did this happen? I have read some documention but didn't get the answer.It really confused me.

Answer (score 0):

On modern Docker installations, try to avoid using the default bridge network.  `docker network create` a network (it doesn't need any special options, but it does need to be created) and then launch your containers on `--net` that network.  If you're using Compose, it creates a ("user bridge") network named `default` for you.

---

On your CentOS host, if you run `ifconfig`, you should see a `docker0` interface with the 172.17.0.1 address.  When you launch a container with the `docker run -p` option, that container is accessible via the first port number on all host interfaces, including the `docker0` interface.

Meanwhile, inside a container (on the default bridge network), it sees that same IP address as the normal IPv4 gateway address (try `docker run --rm busybox route -n`).  So, when you connect to `172.17.0.1:3306`, you're connecting out to the host, and then connecting to the published port of the database container.

This isn't a totally standard way to connect between containers, though it will work.  You should prefer using Docker named networks, which will let you connect to another container using the container's name without manually doing any IP-address lookups.  If you really can't move off of the default bridge network, then the standard approach is to `--link` to the other container, but this entire path is considered outdated.